# Is there an actual use case that requires getAttributeNode and/or getAttributeNodeNS?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web-applications

Can someone think of an *actual use case* whereby we will **ever** require the use of `getAttributeNode` and/or `getAttributeNodeNS`?

As far as I know, `getAttribute` and/or `getAttributeNS` settles all use cases, hence this question.

Comment: So, like, you're going to suggest that they drop that from the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It lets you obtain the item as a Node, which is an interface shared by other DOM components like elements, processing instructions, comments, etc., so you could treat it similarly to other items. Not sure why, but u could... :)

For example:

```
<button id="choose_attr">choose attribute node</button>
<button id="choose_text">choose text node</button>
<button id="getchosennodevalue">get chosen node's value</button>

<script>
var chosenNode;
document.getElementById('choose_attr').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    chosenNode = e.target.getAttributeNode('id'); // Attribute node
}, false);
document.getElementById('choose_text').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    chosenNode = e.target.firstChild; // Text node
}, false);

document.getElementById('getchosennodevalue').addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert(chosenNode.nodeValue); // We can get the value with a shared property, no matter if it is a text node, comment node, element, attribute node, etc.
}, false);
</script>
```

Even if you will only use the variable for storing attribute nodes, one might prefer to have it already pre-built into a special object distinct from other types like strings.

Although your question was about getAttributeNode*, as far as the use of attribute nodes in general, I think it might be more handy with the likes of `document.createAttribute` where you can create and then pass around such a node to set it on an element later. But getting an existing attribute indeed seems of less general utility (though one could imagine a situation where you were passing around attribute nodes, sometimes created anew without an element, and sometimes retrieved from an existing element--using getAttributeNode allows you to avoid building your own object which has getters and setters and handle them with the same interface).

Comment: well i don't see how this example justifies why we have `getAttributeNode`

Comment: It just demonstrates a kind of polymorphism regardless of the type of node--allowing you to conveniently treat an attribute node commonly with other nodes (though the Node interface also has `nodeType` allowing you to distinguish nodes like attribute nodes from other nodes where you DO want to distinguish the type).

Answer (score 1):

It's true there's rarely a reason to use `getAttributeNode()`.  However, I've found it useful in the past as a workaround to Internet Explorer's `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` bugs.  For instance, take the following HTML:

```
<div id="test" onclick="alert()">
```

and the following code:

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");
alert(typeof test.getAttribute("onclick"));
```

Internet Explorer 7 and lower will report `function` in the alert, unlike newer versions and other browsers which correctly report `string`.  The workaround involves `getAttributeNode()`:

```
alert(typeof test.getAttributeNode("onclick").nodeValue);
```

Correctly outputs `string` in all browsers, albeit at a small performance cost.  The same problem applies to boolean and other non-string properties that can be set via attributes.  Sure, this wouldn't be necessary if IE didn't have the bug, but it makes me thankful there's an alternative to `getAttribute()`.

I've set up an example for you to test and play around with — http://jsfiddle.net/PVjn5/.  There's also [a ticket I filed](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9102) over at jQuery.com about it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use them in a situation where you needed to encapsulate the attribute name and value (and namespace, if applicable) in a single object. Use cases for doing this when manipulating a HTML user interface via JavaScript are likely to be rare. However, browsers implement the [DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) and those methods must be provided to meet the spec. The are plenty of use cases for the DOM when it is not being used to manipulate HTML-based user interfaces.